# identify M.2 SSD from BASH Script

Tags: command-line, bash, ssd, nvme

I am writing an installation automation BASH script. I'd like to install the `nvme-cli` package only if an NVMe SSD is actually present.
I couldn't find a simple way to query the hardware (say, using `lshw`) to get a kind-of-yes-or-no answer.
Any of you can give a way to extract the specific answer from within a BASH  script?
I'd like to use the `case` conditioning to either install it or not.

Comment: Is there some reason to not install the package regardless?  Its not big.  And there may be a case where hardware gets upgraded later, after the installation.

Comment: Are these physical hosts of various specs, or are you using virtual machines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, free space is an issue, besides, i am a firm believer in not installing redundant packaged as a rule, so, eventually I went with:

```
 NVMECOUNT=`lsblk | grep nvme | wc -l`
    if [ $NVMECOUNT -gt 1 ]
    then 
        apt -y install nvme-cli
    fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not mine.  This is what worked for you.

Answer (score 14):

A directory test is sufficient:
(the path `/sys/class/nvme` is created by the module `nvme`. However, this does not say anything about the operational state of the drive(s) or even if a drive exists, though).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -d /sys/class/nvme ]]; then
  apt-get -y install nvme-cli
fi
```

Or, if you prefer using globbing to check for the existence of a file(s), a `for`-loop will have the advantage of avoiding a subshell:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for _ in /dev/nvme*; do
  apt-get -y install nvme-cli; break
done
```

Also, if you can, you should avoid globbing as an argument, where there are alternatives, e.g., in this case, the use of `echo` or `printf` is preferable (which is, in reality, a loop construct).

```
shopt -s nullglob
if [[ -n $(echo /dev/nvme*) ]]; then
  apt-get -y install nvme-cli
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dmesg | grep -q nvme
if [ $? = 0 ]  ; then 
      apt install nvme-cli -y
fi
```

All of these solutions should work about the same; they're all testing to see if the kernel has found a NVME device in any way.

If the installer runs at boot, this is probably adequate.  If the installer might run long after boot, then the first line would be better as:

```
grep -q nvme /var/log/dmesg
```

Comment: Thank you all. I havn't realised it is so simple a solution...

Comment: Kernel message buffer is a ring buffer. If a lot of messages have been emitted (e.g. due to long uptime), they'll overwrite the older ones, and this method will give false negative.

Comment: @Ruslan excellent point.

Comment: It's worth noting that, while this might work on Ubuntu, other linux setups might have access to dmesg restricted to the root user. So, if you're planning to run this on other distros, or if ubuntu changes kernel.dmesg_restrict, you might want to use a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if any nvme device files exist:

```
if ls /dev/nvme*
then 
    echo "Install NVME-CLI" 
fi
```

Comment: You might also want to ignore the output of ls with `ls /dev/nvme* &>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using lsscsi:

```
 NVMECOUNT=`lsscsi | grep nvme | wc -l`
    if [ $NVMECOUNT -gt 1 ]
    then 
        echo "Install NVME-CLI" 
    fi
```

Comment: `lsscsi` isn't installed as default, it may seem a bit unnecessary to install one package to test if you need to install another.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the nvme driver is loaded

```
if grep -q nvme /proc/devices
then 
    echo "Install NVME-CLI" 
fi
```